# Python script run from AirFlow job takes UTC time

Tags: python, datetime, airflow

I have an AirFlow job scheduled and running. It calls a Python script where I am using the `datetime.now()` function to get the Date and Time values and store it in a SQL table.

Since it runs via AirFlow, the time that gets saved in the SQL table is in UTC.

Is there a way to pass the current time value through AirFlow or how to get local (+5.30 in my case) time in the SQL table?

The time needs to be in a proper format so that it can be used for other calculations.

Comment: How is UTC not a "proper format"?

Comment: @jonrsharpe, thanks for replying. Issue here is that from the script few more data are being saved. And those data needs to used with local time not UTC. My ask was how to make the data saved with local date and time instead of changing it afterwards

Comment: And we have data coming from a local source where the time is local. Hence there is a conflict with both different time formats

Comment: As long as that local time _is local time_, i.e. has an offset, that shouldn't be a problem. If you're treating local time as UTC _then_ trying to do calculations or comparisons you'll have problems.